# Is there a streaming music service that plays music by year or decade (esp 60s to 80s) based on what was actually popular in the decade?

Tags: history, genre, rock, pop

I find that most “decade channels” (eg 80s Music) play music based on a retrospective notion of the decade. In that, some songs are overplayed and some songs are forgotten. I want to (re-) hear the music that was actually popular in the decade, proportionately, and by radio format, eg ‘soft rock hits as though this were a radio station in 1982’.

Comment: If not, you might have identified a niche....

Comment: Yes, it would seem that no such thing exists.